# How to stop the main thread sequence with respect to time delay?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am trying to load UIActivityIndicatorView custom class, however, I am trying to embed generic time delay before a new view pop's up after my UIActivityIndicatorView shows. I tried the perform afterDelay part, but that doesn't supposedly stop the main thread but rather execute something after 5 seconds. What I am looking for is something that could actually stop the execution until 5 seconds have been elapsed. Is there anyway to do this in iPhone? I can certainly write another method and invoke the new view popup in there after certain delay, but then I would have to invoke this way generally on every viewController. Is there any generic way to bypass this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UI activity indicator won't show until you exit to the main run loop.  The way to stop execution of your app is to exit (return from) your current method.

To finish doing stuff after 5 seconds, put it in another method, and use an NSTimer or delayed operation queue to restart your app's processing.  This is the generic solution that won't cause the UI (and activity indicators) to freeze up.

Comment: I did exactly just like that, but it seams my timer for some reason is not triggering. My timer looks like this.. NSTimer *time; time = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 invocation:nil repeats:NO]; then I stop animating my uiactivityindicator.

Comment: Where is the continuation method specified in your timer?

Comment: well I was in impression that the timer would basically put a delay on the transaction of next execution, or I guess I am mixing this with sleep method?

Comment: It will put a delay if you return immediately after setting the timer.  Try a return statement.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do that, blocking the main thread is BAD and can lead to 8badf00d. Think about redesigning your solution to avoid blocking the main thread.

Comment: well this is just temporary, until I actually invoke the app in the device and actually get some real time delay's rather than simulator, which is extensively very FAST.. However, if you notice there are some apps, that does that like bank of america login, just my 2 cents here. I know its a very bad design feature.